# Replace second value if count is greater than one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query

```
select * from a;
```

Now it returns me three rows like

```
ID NAME VALUE

1   A     B

2   A     C

3   D     E
```

Now what I want is if **NAME** repeats then **XYZ** would be return instead of `A` .

How could I do this?

Comment: What's the desired result? `A...XYZ...D` or `XYZ...XYZ...D`?

Comment: desired result is A...XYZ...D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
ID, 
IF(Name = @prev, 'XYZ', Name) AS Name,
Value
, @prev:=Name
FROM a
, (SELECT @prev:=NULL) var
ORDER BY ID
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/583c6a/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then try

```
SELECT t1.id,
       CASE
       WHEN t1.c > 1 THEN 'xyz'
       ELSE name AS n,
       t1.value
FROM
(
SELECT id,name,count(name) c,value
FROM a 
GROUP BY name
) t1
```